# What is a good way to find the closest 100 matches to a single index/hash when comparing it to 2M+ indexes/hashes stored in a MySQL Table?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have a single hash/index in PHP which I need to compare to a table with 2M+ rows.

If I compare using like, '=' it will try to find me exact matches.

I would instead like to find the closest matches using a hamming distance.

How do I show the closest 100 matches and order them.

Thoughts to consider:
When comparing the given hash/index to the table, there will be 2M+ distances calculated, which will be difficult to order.

Progress so far:
Use php to do an insert sort into an array of 100 elements and then remove the last element every time a smaller distance is found, then update my 'threshhold' value to the 100th element so that I reduce the number of values needed to be inserted over time.

Comment: We see your Specification. Now can we see your workings out

Comment: I assume hamming distance is not the maximum legal distance which I am allowed to be away from bacon at any given time, right? `select * from your_table order by hamming_distance_function(column1, 'your hash/index') limit 100`

Comment: @RiggsFolly workings out provided. Please un-downvote my question.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus the hamming distance is calculated between two hash's/indexes. Therefore every time a new input hash is provided, the distances from the 2M+ records would have to be calculated and ordered.

Comment: A pair of hashes that are close do _not_ say that the original values are "close".  Please elaborate on the goal.  Example:  MD5('abcdefg') = "7ac66c0f148de9519b8bd264312c4d64" but MD5('abcdefG') = "b75cf09fe732203cf2389bea4c646c27".

Comment: @RickJames The hashes were not created using md5. 

They were created using phash. where the distance does imply closeness. 
http://www.phash.org/

Answer (score 0):

Hamming distance is inherently "Order N".  That is, a table scan.

Search mathematical literature for the complexity of searching by hamming distance.  If you find something that is faster than O(N), let's discuss it.

Barring that, I suspect you would have to invent some kludge such as:

- Check the 'distance' to every 'word' that starts with the same letter.
- Check the 'distance' to every 'word' that has the same second letter.
- Etc

The 'length' of the 'word' might also be a factor?

That would be clumsy, and might involve extra tables and/or extra indexes, and would involve a bunch of application code.  And it would take a lot of disk space.

Comment: My question is more to do with how do I get the top 100 closest matches out of 2M+ records? This is different from a text search, since this means finding 2M+ distances, and then sorting them to find the least 100.

Comment: The problem is that there is no pattern.  Ordinary indexes (and dictionaries) work quite efficiently because they can take advantage of the 1-dimensional nature of a sorted list of words.  When looking up a city on a printed map, you end up with 2-dimensional coordinates ("C-7").  But hamming distance is similar to an N-dimensional problem, when N is the number of letters.  If you can explain how Hamming is really 1D (or even 2D), MySQL can help.